# To get Ip address and login time and logout time in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, ip

I created one website in asp.net with c#. in that i have to show visitor details to admin and store in database.. about visitor's logged in time, logout time and then their IP Address [currently in which system they are using to access our website]. i have no idea about to do this.please any one guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        var props = OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageProperties;
        var endpointProperty = props[RemoteEndpointMessageProperty.Name] as RemoteEndpointMessageProperty;
        if (endpointProperty != null)
        {
            objIP.Address = endpointProperty.Address;
            objIP.Port = endpointProperty.Port;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple as

```
Response.Write("Your IP address is: " + Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"].ToString() + "<br />");

Response.Write("You are browsing this site with: " + Request.ServerVariables["http_user_agent"].ToString() + "<br />");

Response.Write("The method used to call the page: " + Request.ServerVariables["request_method"].ToString() + "<br />");

Response.Write("The server's domain name: " + Request.ServerVariables["server_name"].ToString() + "<br />");

Response.Write("The server's port: " + Request.ServerVariables["server_port"].ToString() + "<br />");

Response.Write("The server's software: " + Request.ServerVariables["server_software"].ToString() + "<br />");

Response.Write("The DNS lookup of the IP address is: " + Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_HOST"].ToString());
```